# Desempenho do relacionamento do Eloquent do Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Eu percebo que no `Laravel 4 Framework`, quando temos um relacionamento, ao invés de utilizar um `JOIN` do `Mysql` no código fonte do `Eloquent`, ele usa um select.

Por exemplo. Tenho esses dois Models.

```
class Usuario extends Eloquent{

   public function nivel()
   {
       return $this->belongsTo('Nivel');
   }
}

class Nivel extends Eloquent
{

}
```

Quando eu faço a seguinte consulta:

```
$usuarios = Usuario::with('nivel')->get();

foreach($usuarios as $usuario) {

   echo $usuario->nivel->nome;
}
```

E utilizo o `DB::getQueryLog()`, ao invés de exibir isso:

```
SELECT * FROM usuarios JOIN niveis ON niveis.id = usuarios.nivel_id
```

Ele faz isso

```
SELECT * FROM usuarios
SELECT * FROM niveis WHERE id IN(5, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```

E isso porque eu usei o `with('nivel')`. Pois se eu utilizasse fizesse isso:

```
$usuarios = Usuario::all();

foreach($usuarios as $usuario){

   echo $usuario->nivel->nome;
}
```

O retorno do `DB::getQueryLog()` seria esse, caso existam 3 usuários:

```
SELECT * FROM usuarios
SELECT * FROM niveis WHERE id = 1
SELECT * FROM niveis WHERE id = 1
SELECT * FROM niveis WHERE id = 3
```

Ou seja, quando não especifico o `with`, se eu tiver 100 usuários no resultado, ele fará 100 selects para relacionar com a tabela níveis

Gosto muito de usar o `Laravel 4` por conta de sua ótima produtividade e organização.

Porém gostaria de saber se esse "select separado" que ele faz poderia implicar em perda de performance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esse recurso do qual você está falando se chama [eager loading](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading). Ele verifica as os vínculos entre as tabelas e diminui o número de *queries* para aumentar a performance da sua aplicação.

Num primeiro momento, é mais fácil analisar o seu problema considerando-se a quantidade de *queries* executadas: o número caiu de 1+n para apenas 1 ou 2 *queries*, no caso de haver resultados para a primeira *query*. Nesse caso é bastante provável que o eager loading tenha ajudado sua aplicação em termos de performance.

Quando ao fato do Laravel fazer duas *queries* ao invés de fazer apenas uma usando `JOIN`, acredito que o motivo seja o fato dele desconhecer a estrutura do seu banco de dados. Provavelmente a decisão técnica do Eloquent fazer duas consulta é que, na segunda consulta, ele a faz usando a chave primária da tabela que, por característica, já é indexada e com certeza traz bons resultados.

Por outro lado, consultas com `JOIN`s, em muitos casos, costumam ser custosas e nesse caso o próprio desenvolvedor deveria escrever as queries na aplicação, ao invés de confiar no Eloquent para isso.

Comment: +1. principalmente por agora eu conseguir entender o que era esse tal de Eager Loading!

Comment: Gosto de usar o [laravel-debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) para monitorar as querys da minha aplicação. Além de mostrar todas as querys executadas tem uma opção dele que roda automaticamente o `explain` da query.

Comment: Esse debugbar é muito bom. Usei nos projetos Laravel com os que trabalhei, também.