# O que é Lazy Loading e Eager Loading?

Tags: php, cakephp, independente-de-linguagem, carga-antecipada, carga-preguiçosa

- O que é **Lazy Loading** e **Eager Loading**?

Vi estes termos em uma documentação, mas não entendi muito bem, então minha duvida é saber o que estes termos significam e gostaria de, se possível, restringir o escopo da resposta/pergunta a `PHP` e `CakePHP` (Framework MVC com ORM embutido), pois são as tecnologias onde estou tendo mais contato ultimamente e onde vi os termos.

Comment: O `Laravel 4` também usa o tal do `Eager Loading Constrains`

Comment: É independente de linguagem ou PHP? Fiquei confuso :P

Comment: @jbueno independente, coloquei PHP só para exemplificar.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## **Eager Loading**

É o Load aonde todas as classes relacionadas são carregadas na mesma query.
O ORM, normalmente por meio de Joins, trará todas as entidades relacionadas.

**Exemplo de uso**

Você tem uma entidade *Lista*, onde ela tem várias entidades *Item* (one to many), na sua entidade *Lista* existe um atributo com uma  Collection de *Items*.

Quando você executar um Find() ou algum comando para trazer esses objetos todas as suas relações são carregadas de imediato, ou seja, na sua *Lista* já estarão carregados na memória todos os seus *Items* (nesse exemplo).

Logo, esses objetos já podem ser referenciados.

Em certos casos o **Eager loading** torna-se desnecessário, pois nem sempre quando se carrega uma entidade você deseja ter carregado em memória as entidades relacionadas.

Exemplo de load com **Eager loading** dos *Items* relacionados a *Lista*:

```
// Usando em conjunto com o find()
$query = $listas->find('all', ['contain' => ['Items']]);

// Como um método query no objeto
$query = $listas->find('all');
$query->contain(['Items']);
```

Note que podem ser definidas mais de uma relação com o contain

## **Lazy Loading**

como o próprio nome diz, é um carregamento preguiçoso, quando você executa uma consulta por uma certa Entidade suas relações não são carregadas em memória pela consulta inicial, no entanto, ao executar algum método que chama esses registros, será executada uma outra consulta para preencher essas entidades relacionadas.

**Exemplo**

Seguindo o exemplo de *Listas* e a entidade relacionada *Item*, se você usasse por exemplo um método GetItems() da *Lista*, o ORM executaria uma query e carregaria essas entidades para você.

**Loads no CakePHP**

Segundo a documentação do CakePHP o **Lazy Loading** deve ser implementado por você, ou seja, o ORM não vai fazer isso de forma automática.

**Exemplo de uso**

Neste exemplo as relações *Lista* x *Item* são carregadas manualmente na entidade *Lista*.

```
 namespace App\Model\Entity;

 use Cake\ORM\Entity;
 use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

class Lista extends Entity
{

    protected function _getItems()
    {
        $items = TableRegistry::get('Items');
        return $items->find('all')
            ->where(['lista_id' => $this->id])
            ->toArray();
    }

}
```

*Documentação Eager X Lazy CakePHP:*
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/entities.html#lazy-loading-associations

Answer (score 8):

Um exemplo clássico disso em PHP seria dado com Laravel.

Por exemplo:

Se temos um model de Usuário que relaciona com várias Compras, poderiamos acessar essas compras assim

```
$usuarios = Usuario::all();

foreach($usuarios as $usuario)

    foreach($usuario->compras as $compra)
        echo "ID DA COMPRA é " . $compra->id
```

Porém, ao fazer isso, para cada iteração, seria feito uma nova consulta na tabela de compras, para relacionar com o usuário no qual se requer a informação de quais compras ele tem.

Imagina se você tem 100 usuários em um sistema e cada esteja vinculado a 20 compras?

Isso somaria 20.000 (vinte mil) queries executadas!

Isso, no Laravel 4, seria contornado da seguinte forma:

```
Usuario::with('compras')->all();
```

Assim, ao invés de 50 queries executadas, você teria apenas duas queries executadas!

O último exemplo seria o tal do Eager Load!

Veja a pergunta que fiz a respeito disso em [Desempenho do Eloquent no Laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/48692/desempenho-do-relacionamento-do-eloquent-do-laravel)

Comment: "Isso somaria 20.000 (vinte mil) queries executadas!" Na verdade você está interpretando mal, pois as queries são executadas com joins e uma query pode retornar mais de um registro por vez

Comment: Não estou não, Fernando. Eu já fiz testes. No Laravel não é utilizado `JOINS`. Eu estou falando de algo que já comprovei

Comment: Se você usar o relacionamento do laravel sem a função `with`, para cada interação ele faz uma query. É assim sim! Ele não usa um SELECT pra cada tabela (representada pelo model). Exemplo `Usuario[1, 2, 3], SELECT * FROM compras where usuario_id = 1`. E assim, para cada um dos três.

Comment: Entendi, me desculpe.