# .Include() não carrega classe filha - Lazyloading C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

Eu estava usando o Modelo DDD com Repositorios e  com 3 camadas de dados, (`Serviço`,`Repositorio` e `Dominio`), com a ajuda de alguns usuários aqui eu resolvi mudar o projeto e agora acabei por remover 2 camadas a `serviço` e a `repositório` do meu projeto.

Estou ainda estudando sobre este assunto que esta cada vez ficando mais claro para mim (agora entendo porque meu codigo era prolixo, como dito pelo usário @jbueno), eu tenho meu contexto declarado e estou usando a versão do 6.0 do EntityFramework.

Eu criei uma controller na minha camada `Web` e fiz a seguinte pesquisa :

```
 List<MensagemUnidade> mensagens = this.Contexto.MensagemUnidade
            .Include(c => c.Cliente).Where(l => l.UnidadeId == unidade.UnidadeAtual && l.OrigemId == (int)enumOrigemMensagem.ADMIN)
            .OrderByDescending(l => l.DataEnvio).Skip(mensagemModel.PaginaAtual * 20)
            .Take(20)               
            .ToList();
```

Ela não trouxe o cliente,

Essa e minha classe `Cliente`:

```
public class Cliente : Pessoa
{
    public string FacebookFoto { get; set; }

    public ICollection<TokenCliente> TokensCliente { get; set; }
}
```

Minha classe `MensagemUnidade`:

```
 public class MensagemUnidade
  {
     public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
     public virtual Unidade Unidade { get; set; }
  }
```

O LazyLoading esta ativado,ele ate carrega o `ClienteId` Correto mas o Cliente fica `null`.

Eu estava com o modelo DDD e usando `Repositorio`, o meu projeto agora possui a seguinte estrutura, uma camada `Dominio`, uma  Camada `Infra`(onde fica meu `contexto` e minhas camadas `Web/API` , quando eu mudei o projeto fiquei em duvida sobre `UnitofWork`e coisas do tipo, agora esta tudo se encaixando melhor, mas ainda tenho esse problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você só precisa explicitar na sua classe de relação que `Cliente` é uma entidade que será carregada a partir da chave `ClienteId`. Como `Cliente` é uma classe que herda de `Pessoa` e quem tem a `PrimaryKey` é esta segunda, rola uma certa confusão.

```
public class MensagemUnidade
{
    public int ClienteId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ClienteId")]
    public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }        
 }
```

Uma observação importante sobre a seguinte frase

> O LazyLoading esta ativado,ele ate carrega o ClienteId Correto mas o Cliente fica null.

O LazyLoading não é necessário para se usar o `Include`. Na verdade, quando se usa `Include` se está falando de **eager loading** (ou carga antecipada) e não de **lazy loading** (carga preguiçosa).

Em suma, a principal diferença entre os dois é que usando técnicas de **eager loading** (`Include`, `Load`) a entidade é carregada em memória no momento que *query* é materializada ([veja mais sobre isso aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/113634/18246)), isto é, a consulta que é executada no banco de dados, já contém as informações referentes às entidades explicitadas (no seu caso, usando o método `Include`). Já no **lazy loading**, as entidades relacionadas são apenas *proxies* e a consulta delas só será executada no banco quando você tentar acessar a entidade.

Aqui tem uma publicação interessante sobre o assunto: [O que é Lazy Loading e Eager Loading?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/75632/18246)