# Otimização de site em PHP/CSS3/HTML5/MySQL

Tags: php, otimização

Sou novo aqui, li sobre as regras, mas não sei onde postar isso, gostaria de uma ajuda, sobre como melhorar o carregamento de um site desenvolvido em PHP/CSS3/HTML5/MySQL, alguém indica um site ou uma biblioteca para integrar no site que ajuda com minify, como por exemplo a biblioteca gerar uma versão minify em um diretório a partir do código original, mas mantendo o original e lendo o minificado. O problema em gerar páginas estáticas é que realmente o conteúdo do site muda diariamente, o problema não está em ler o banco de dados em tempo de processamento no carregamento da página, pois está bem ágil, mas ainda preciso melhorar o carregamento do site, já uso cache de imagens, gerador de imagens redimensionadas na medida que as imagens são carregadas pela primeira vez, ele gera a miniatura, que reduz 70% sem perder a resolução, e depois é reutilizada, mas gostaria de mais conteúdo para ler ou uma biblioteca flexivel para implementar no website. Grato!

Comment: Cara o próprio Dev Tools do Chrome tem uma série de recursos para te ajudar e descobrir e corrigir problemas de performance. Inclusive ele tem uma Aba exclusiva para testar a performance, para fazer auditorias de desempenho e avaligar os carregamentos de tudo que é indexado na página. Se te interessar e vc achar que seria válido como uma resposta eu posso dar mais detalhes

Comment: Oi @hugocsl por favor me forneça mais detalhes, desde já grato por isso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiramente essa resposta não aborda todos os pontos que devem ser tratados, ela tem como base apenas o `Chrome Dev Tools` como ferramente de análise de performance e otimização.

Vou usar algumas imagens como exemplo, repare sempre nas marcações em vermelho (setas, quadrados e linhas) que fiz nas imagens. Vou dar uma explicação básica de cada ponto que vc pode usar para tratar a performance baseado no que o Dev Tools mostra. *Não que o Dev Tools seja a opção perfeita, nem tudo que ele acusa merece ou deve ser levado em consideração.*

Primeiro na `Aba Network`, repare que tudo que está depois da linha vermelha é pq a requisição demorou de mais para retornar, tudo que estiver ali vc pode verificar a possibilidade de diminuir o tamanho do arquivo, minificar, tratar imagem ou vídeo, tirar uma font-family etc. Repare que vc pode filtrar apenas por IMG, JS ou Tudo (All).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

`Aba Performance` aqui é parecido com a aba Network, vc pode avaliar qual a porcentagem do tamanho da sua página por tipo de arquivo. Repare que nessa página a maior parte do tempo de renderização fica por conta dos scripts, talvez ali vc possa tratar algo, ou retirar alguma coisa. Repare também no que está além da linha vermelha.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

`Aba Coverage`, essa aba mostra quanto do seu código vc realmente está usando na página, repare que essa página tem Bootstrap, porém **só 10% do CSS está sendo usado**, 90% está lá só ocupado espaço, repara tb que só 50% do jQuery está sendo usado, só ai vc já pode economizar uns 100kb.  **OBS:** Na parte do Source onde tem a linha vermelha a esquerda mostra o que do CSS não está sendo usado!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

`Aba Audits` aqui vc pode fazer uma auditoria mais próxima da auditoria que o motor de busca do Google faz. Tudo que for acusado ali é pq o Google pode levar em consideração na nota do seu site e conseqüentemente no seu rankeamento nas pesquisas. Repare que ele marca de vermelho a parte crítica, e fornece um "dropdown" para vc ver e verificar o que pode trabalhar para melhor a nota do site e a sua performance.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**OBS 1:** Além disso, vc pode ler sobre **Lazy Loading** nesse questão, ela pode te ajudar a otimizar o carregamento da página [O que é Lazy Loading e Eager Loading?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/75632/o-que-%C3%A9-lazy-loading-e-eager-loading)

> Lazy loading é um padrão de projeto de software, comumente utilizado em linguagens de programação, para adiar a inicialização de um objeto até o ponto em que ele é necessário. Isso pode contribuir para a eficiência no funcionamento de um programa, se utilizado adequadamente.

*Fonte:* https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading

**OBS 2:** Trate com exclusividade a parte do código "Above de Fold". Isso quer dizer que vc deve otimizar principalmente o conteúdo que vem antes da primeira dobra da página, ou seja todo o código necessário para renderizar a página antes que o usuário de o primeiro scroll, pois o conteúdo que veem abaixo da dobra não tem a necessidade de ser renderizado com prioridade.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
*Fonte:* https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/08/understanding-critical-css/

Vc pode ler mais sobre isso na documentação do Google Page Speed: https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/PrioritizeVisibleContent

Comment: Perfeito, a abordagem 360º da sua resposta é de grande valia, vou se autorizado por você, compartilhar o link da página em alguns grupos de desenvolvedores em uma rede social que participo, geralmente de iniciantes e intermediários.

Comment: @AngeloJ muito legal sua iniciativa, eu tentei englobar tudo que eu conhecida além do já citado por vc. O problema é que boa parte desse assunto eu só conheço em teoria, pois tenho pouca prática. Muito sucesso pra vc abs!

Comment: Gratidão bro!!!!